# How can I translate a Web Dynpro button?

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I have the following button that I want to translate: (highlighted with yellow)

[image]

The translations are maintained in transaction `SOTR_EDIT` (for DE, EN and ES), but if I logon in EN/ES, I still see the text in DE.

The only difference between this button and the rest (which are correctly translated) is the package to which they are assigned.

Is this relevant? Where should I check more? In ST05 / ST12 traces, I did not find any relevant data.

Comment: Maybe reset the OTR buffer (from SAP GUI command field, enter `/$OTR`). If it doesn't work reset the ICM cache (transaction code `SMICM` > menu Goto > HTTP Plug-in > Server cache > Invalidate globally)

Comment: Tried both OTR buffer and ICM cache resets, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First point. Check if you are deal with the text you are intended to. There can be multiple texts with the same name in different packages. Check all.

[image]

Second. Go to translation workbench (`SE63` tcode) and search for you text by fetching all the text through package name + wildcard

[image]

[image]

Find your text by concept which you can take from `SOTR_EDIT` and check if it really translated

[image]

If there is red color like here then translation is missing

[image]

Comment: 1) Text "Sammelaviseirung exportieren" is he only one in SOTR_EDIT (so I cant confuse if with a text from another package). 2) I checked SE63 and translation is not missing. However, I edited the text in SE63, but I still saw the original text in UI. I must now check if the button text was overwritten in code, or even just hardcoded from the first place.

Comment: Apparently the text was hard-coded in a post-exit method. But with the provided info, I was able to edit the text in SE63 and find out that the SOTR_EDIT text is not even being used. So, lots of thanks for the help.